# How is a mail secured using mail or s/mime certificate?

Tags: security, encryption, certificate

I am trying to understand how a mail is secured using mail or s/mime certificate ?

Normally HTTPS has certificate in a server which gets downloaded to the client on the request reply and then it goes on for few steps till it both arrive at a symmetric key and then encryption will be done using these keys.

From my reading I felt it is not the same case in a mail send/receive.

How does a mail certificate secure a mail in case of for Eg. **outlook** ?
I know a personal certificate can be used per email address for signing and the public key has to be shared with the sender.

But if that is not the case , will there be  one certificate installed at the mail server for all users ? When does it get downloaded to the mail client.

Whether a email client have to install a mail certificate ?

Any answers or a link to a resource will be greatly appreciated . Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with C#. When you tag a question please use relevant tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to encrypt a message using S/MIME you already need to have a copy of the recipient's certificate - there's no automatic exchange of certificates as part of the protocol, in the way you would get with SSL.  In a system with a central LDAP directory (e.g. a corporate email server) there are standard ways for a mail client to request the certificate for a particular user from the LDAP server, but in the general case you simply have to ask the recipient to send you their certificate separately.

However you obtain the certificate, the important thing is that trust is established in the same way as for SSL - each certificate is issued (and signed) by an authority certificate, and your mail client settings determine which root authorities you trust.

Comment: I have a simple question. For a client to decrypt an encrypted mail he will need to have a private key since a public key would have been used to encrypt it. Since the reading goes on in the mail client, is the certificate installed on the mail client of the receiver ? If so when is it installed. I am not  talking about a case where I bought  a personal certificate and shared it with the sender. This is a case where I have a outlook client  installed on my machine and there is a mail exchange server somewhere and mail is secured.

Comment: @Chandan I think you may be getting confused between s/mime, which uses certificates to encrypt and/or sign the message content itself, and TLS used to encrypt the connection between client and server. The two are unrelated and independent. S/MIME uses certificates that belong to individuals and provides end-to-end security regardless of how many "hops" the message takes, TLS uses certificates that belong to machines and protects just the data transfer in a single hop.

Comment: @Chandan the main benefit of using TLS is with authenticated SMTP to protect the username and password from packet sniffers, rather than to protect the content of the message.

Comment: I was talking about S/Mime. So are you saying there will be as many certificates as the number of user accounts and the mail client  will be pre-installed with the certificate of the particular user of that client ? If not how can  he read his message which was encrypted by the sender ?

Comment: @Chandan X.509 certificates as use in S/MIME are a form of public-key cryptography. Each person (i.e. each email address) has a private key, which they keep secret, and a corresponding certificate, which is public knowledge.  When you want to send an encrypted message to someone you need to look up _their_ certificate (from the LDAP server, or a local cache of certificates you've been sent, or whatever) and use that to encrypt and _your own_ private key to sign.  The receipient then uses their own private key to decrypt the message and your public certificate to verify the signature.

Comment: Since private key of the Public/private key is in the server and is supposed to be kept secret/protected, how will the mail decryption be carried out for the recipient? (Decryption will be done only by a private key). Will the private key get downloaded to the mail client ?  I am sorry if I might be asking something very obvious , but please bear with me.

Comment: @Chandan each user's private key is stored on their own machine by their mail client, only the certificates (the public part) need to be transferred to the sender.